# formulate linear programming constraints

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, pulp

I have a problem to formulate a second constraint for my linear programming application.

I am inspired by the article of: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-solve-a-staff-scheduling-problem-with-python-63ae50435ba4

But in this article the total number of shifts are limited. If I want to limit my number of total workers I need a new constraint which is formulated roughly like this:

My total number of workers does not limit above z

How would I formulate this constraint in python (pulp) ?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have tried?

Comment: for sure,
z = 24
prob += pl.lpSum(y[j] for j in range(n)] >= z

Comment: Would you mind checking this ```prob+= lpSum(y[j] for j in range(n) <= TOTAL_WORKERS``` replacing total workers with your max workers

Comment: yeah I checked it and I don't know what exactly this constraint optimises, but obviously it does not limit my total number of workers

Comment: I think you need a mapping between each worker and the shifts they can perform (and how many shifts). That is not in the data you refer to.